# TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSupportedConstraints' of undefined (when serve on host as IP address)

Tags: angularjs, undefined, navigator, mediadevices

I am facing a wired issue when i run my angularjs application on my localhost it is working fine.
But when I host it on IP address it gives error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSupportedConstraints' of undefined

This is my code

```
let mediaSourceSupport = !!navigator.mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints()
    .mediaSource;
```

when serve on localhost navigator.mediaDevices object I get http://prntscr.com/qpf32s
but when host on IP address it gives undefind

Answer (score 5):

You can also enable `chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` and add your url to it.

Answer (score 0):

This Error will be eliminated when you are running your APP with SSL Encryption on your Production System.

*Encryption based security
The getUserMedia() method is only available in secure contexts. A secure context is one the browser is reasonably confident contains a document which was loaded securely, using HTTPS/TLS, and has limited exposure to insecure contexts. If a document isn't loaded in a secure context, the navigator.mediaDevices property is undefined, making access to getUserMedia() impossible.*

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Privacy_and_security